# How can i update table model multiple row columns?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

I have 3 rows in tablemodel.each row conatining 9 columns (o-8).i want to update last column of every row...but now i can update only 1st rowth last column..pls help..`

```
   ` SAVE=new JButton("SAVE");
     SAVE.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {  
      public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {  
      String Status=null ;
      DbUtility ViewAbsenties=new DbUtility();
      ViewAbsenties. loadDriver();
      ViewAbsenties.connect();
      TableModel tm;
      tm = table3.getModel();
      int i = table3.getRowCount();
      System.out.println("row count"+i);

          try{
            while(i!=0){
              Status   =(String) tm.getValueAt(0,8);
              String Employeeid = (String) tm.getValueAt(i,0);
              System.out.println("Status: " + Status);
              System.out.println("Employeeid: " + Employeeid);
              ViewAbsenties.executeUpdateQuery2(Status,Employeeid);
              System.out.println("i"+i);
               i=i-1;

                  }}
            catch (Exception e5) {

                }
          });
```

Comment: Does it working? Because it seems to me that in the one loop cycle you have `i++` and `i=i-1` which makes the `i` variable unchanged for the loop condition. It looks like an infinity loop. I guess that the solution of your problem lies in that, so remove the `i++` statement, fix `tm.getValueAt(0,0)` to `tm.getValueAt(i,0)` and you should be fine.

Comment: tm.getValueAt(i,0); i tried this but now i did not get any result

Comment: You still have `tm.getValueAt(0,8)` at the first row in the cycle. I guess that you want to process each table row independently. Also I justs noticed that you initialize `int i = table3.getRowCount();` and when you call `tm.getValueAt(i,0)`. I don't know how does it here but in Java the arrays, models etc. are usually indexed from `0` to `length - 1`, but you are calling them from `1` to `length`. So I suggest you the following fixes: `int i = table3.getRowCount()-1;` and `while(i>=0)`. By the way I think that this is good use case for `for` cycle instead of `while`. It would be more readable

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Hard code the table data.

Comment: You should never have an empty `catch(Exception e)` block. Always print the stacktrace, write a log message or something but never, ever, use an empty catch block. This only makes it harder to debug when something goes wrong.

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
Status   =(String) tm.getValueAt(i,8);
String Employeeid = (String) tm.getValueAt(i,0);
```

instead of

```
Status   =(String) tm.getValueAt(0,8);
String Employeeid = (String) tm.getValueAt(0,0);
```

first argument in getValueAt is rowIndex, and you should pass indexes of rows you want to update but you only update row 0 in loop.

Comment: nicely spotted :-) BTW, you might consider having a look at the [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 1):

I decided to sum up my observations which I mentioned above in comments.

Your code had a couple issues

- in the same loop cycle you call `i++` and `i=i-1` which makes the variant of the cycle to be invariant, so your loop is endless (you already fixed that)
- you are still calling `tm.getValueAt(0,8)`. The first parameter is `rowIndex`, the second is a `columnIndex`. So for each iteration you work still with the first row, not with the current one.
- Java usually indexes models and arrays from `0` to `length - 1` but you are iterate from `length` to `1`. So you need to lower the variable `i` by `1`

There is fixed code:

```
int i = table3.getRowCount() - 1;
while( i >= 0 ){

          Status = (String) tm.getValueAt( i, 8 );
          String Employeeid = (String) tm.getValueAt( i, 0 );

          System.out.println( "Status: " + Status );
          System.out.println( "Employeeid: " + Employeeid );

          ViewAbsenties.executeUpdateQuery2( Status, Employeeid );

          System.out.println( "i" + i );
          i = i - 1;
}
```

**Note:**
Anyway there are my few observations to improve your code style:

- the example above is the exact use case for `for` cycle
- based on Java convention variable names should start with a non-capital letter.

  ```
  for ( int i = 0; i < table3.getRowCount(); ++i ) {
        status = (String) tm.getValueAt( i, 8 );
        String employeeid = (String) tm.getValueAt( i, 0 );

        System.out.println( "Status: " + status );
        System.out.println( "Employeeid: " + employeeid );

        ViewAbsenties.executeUpdateQuery2( status, employeeid );

        System.out.println( "i" + i );
  }
  ```